# MVC C# performing the same operation on different types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, optimization

I am using MVC and wanting a number of multi select boxes in a [create] view.

I have managed to do what I want but with code repetition which clearly I do not want:

My Model:

```
public class ReportCreateModel
{

    public MultiSelectList allDBtables;
    public MultiSelectList allfrequencies;
    public MultiSelectList allsql;

}
```

My Controller:

```
private Context db = new Context();

public ActionResult Create()
{

    ReportCreateModel rcm = new ReportCreateModel();

    //frequencies
    List<SelectListItem> frequencyItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (Frequency f in db.dbFrequency.ToList())
    {

        SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = f.frequencyName,
            Value = f.frequencyID.ToString()
        };

        frequencyItems.Add(item);

    }

    //systems
    List<SelectListItem> systemItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (DataSystem s in db.dbSystem.ToList())
    {

        SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem
        {

            Text = s.systemName,
            Value = s.systemID.ToString()

        };

        systemItems.Add(item);

    }

    //SQL
    List<SelectListItem> sqlItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (SQL s in db.dbSQLUsed.ToList())
    {

        SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem
        {

            Text = s.SQLName + " (" + s.sqltypes.SQLTypeName + ")",
            Value = s.SQLID.ToString()

        };

        sqlItems.Add(item);

    }

    rcm.allfrequencies = new MultiSelectList(frequencyItems, "Value", "Text");
    rcm.allsystems = new MultiSelectList(systemItems, "Value", "Text");
    rcm.allSQL = new MultiSelectList(sqlItems, "Value", "Text");

    return View(rcm);

}
```

This works as required and I can create the listboxes in my view from the MultiSelectLists but can someone please suggest how I can reduce the code so I can just have one code block that runs the code for the specified database entities (dbFrequency,dbSystem,dbSQLUsed)

Comment: This should be posted on [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MatiasCicero no changing the entire code should not be posted on code review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the (penultimate) code in Robert McKee's solution, however, had to adapt it to get it to compile and display correctly in the view:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.AllSystems = new MultiSelectList(db.dbSystem.Select(x=>new { Name=x.systemName, Value=x.systemId }),"Value","Name");
    return View();
}
```

etc....

Answer (score -3):

That code is mostly garbage (it won't compile) and noise.  Start by using consistent [capitalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx) (You call the property allsql in one place, and allSQL in another.  You call the property allsystems in one place and allDBtables in another).  Then don't do unnecessary stuff.

```
private Context db = new Context();

public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new ReportCreateModel
    {
        AllSystems = new MultiSelectList(db.dbSystem,"systemName","systemId"),
        AllFrequencies = new MultiSelctList(db.dbFrequencies, "frequencyName", "frequencyID"),
        AllSql = new MultiSelectList(db.dbSQl.Select(s=>new {NAME=s.SQLName + " (" + s.sqltypes.SQLTypeName + ")",SQLID=s.SQLID}),"NAME","SQLID")
    });

}
```

If you want to further optimize your database access, only ask for the properties you actually need, like this:

```
private Context db = new Context();

public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new ReportCreateModel
    {
        AllSystems = new MultiSelectList(db.dbSystem.Select(x=>new { Name=x.systemName, Value=s.systemId }),"Name","Value"),
        AllFrequencies = new MultiSelectList(db.dbFrequencies.Select(x=>new { Name=x.frequencyName, Value=x.frequencyID }), "Name", "Value"),
        AllSql = new MultiSelectList(db.dbSQl.Select(s=>new { Name=s.SQLName + " (" + s.sqltypes.SQLTypeName + ")", Value=s.SQLID}),"Name","Value")
    });

}
```

Simple capitalization rules:
As a general rule, it is "Sql", not "SQL". "allDBtables" should be "AllDbTables" or "AllDBTables". "allfrequencies" should be "AllFrequencies". "allsql" should be "AllSql".

Actually, it is customary to throw dropdown values into the ViewBag, not into the viewmodel, in which case it'd be:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.AllSystems = new MultiSelectList(db.dbSystem.Select(x=>new { Name=x.systemName, Value=s.systemId }),"Name","Value");
    ViewBag.AllFrequencies = new MultiSelectList(db.dbFrequencies.Select(x=>new { Name=x.frequencyName, Value=x.frequencyID }), "Name", "Value");
    ViewBag.AllSql = new MultiSelectList(db.dbSQl.Select(s=>new { Name=s.SQLName + " (" + s.sqltypes.SQLTypeName + ")", Value=s.SQLID}),"Name","Value");
    return View();
}
```

Then as MultiSelectList is a UI control, it really shouldn't even appear in the controller (separation of concerns).  Then it would simply become:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.AllSystems = db.dbSystem.Select(x=>new { Name=x.systemName, Value=s.systemId });
    ViewBag.AllFrequencies = db.dbFrequencies.Select(x=>new { Name=x.frequencyName, Value=x.frequencyID });
    ViewBag.AllSql = db.dbSQl.Select(s=>new { Name=s.SQLName + " (" + s.sqltypes.SQLTypeName + ")", Value=s.SQLID});
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Amazing that this answer got downvoted 3 times as not useful, yet the OP posted their own answer saying they used my answer.  Apparently it was useful.  Oh well.